# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.richfaces.component.Positioning.bl while migrating RichFaces 3.3.3 to 4.0

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I am migrating my application from RichFaces 3.3.3 to Richfaces 4.0.0. I resolved few errors related to removed tags in Richfaces 4.0.0.

Now I am getting the below exception while loading the home page.

```
23:46:10,317 WARN  [org.jboss.seam.util.Resources] (default task-25) Unable to determine real path from servlet context for "/WEB-INF/dev" path does not exist.
23:46:10,302 ERROR [org.jboss.seam.exception.Exceptions] (default task-22) handled and logged exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: No enum constant org.richfaces.component.Positioning.bl
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at com.action.session.ProjectReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ProjectReplyHeaderFilter.java:59) [Project-ejb.jar:]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.richfaces.component.Positioning.bl
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
at org.jboss.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToEnum(ELSupport.java:158) [jboss-el.jar:1.0_02.CR2]
at org.jboss.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:343) [jboss-el.jar:1.0_02.CR2]
at org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:46) [jboss-el.jar:1.0_02.CR2]
at org.jboss.seam.el.SeamExpressionFactory.coerceToType(SeamExpressionFactory.java:70) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.BeanPropertyTagRule$LiteralPropertyMetadata.applyMetadata(BeanPropertyTagRule.java:88) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.setAttributes(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:115) [richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:408) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:171) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:55) [richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:55) [richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:55) [richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:55) [richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:55) [richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:55) [richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:187) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:323) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:382) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:323) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:382) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:323) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:382) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:323) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:382) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:164) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:914) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.29-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.29.Final.jar:2.1.29.Final]
... 49 more
```

I also observed that the enum value is not available with value .bl for org.richfaces.component.Positioning.bl.

I verified in other Jars aswell, but there is no Enum vulue for bl.

I am not able to understanding, why I am getting this exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A piece of your code is trying to pass "bl" to a method that handles the enum. It's going through EL parser so it's probably somewhere on a XHMTL page.

`org.richfaces.component.Positioning` is used in positioning popup elements, my guess is the problem is in `rich:dropDownMenu` and @jointPoint since that's the only one that mentions "bl" in documentation. In RichFaces 4.X the correct value is "bottomLeft".